# How to perform Multiplicative Inverse Modulo in IDEA

Tags: idea

How to perform the Multiplicative Inverse Modulo in International Data Encryption Algorithm? I don't understand on how to perform it…

For example, let's say I have a value of `cf80` and the value that is appearing to me is this `3080`. This is the thing that I've done based on my understanding:

```
answer = 53120 % 65537  
53120(integer value of 3080) = 3080
```

When I convert the result in hexadecimal, the value is `3080` but the correct result should be `9194`.

Comment: I can't understand your example or your explanation of what you have tried.  Do you want to try to edit it, to explain more clearly?

Comment: Straighten notations. `CF80` in hexadecimal is 53120 in decimal, but not 3080 by any stretch of imagination; that is -3080 modulo 65536, or -3081 modulo 65537; also, 3080 converted to hexadecimal is `0C08`, not `3080`. In the context you want unsigned numbers, and displaying them as such (in decimal or hexadecimal). Most importantly, the multiplicative inverse of $x$ is $y$ such that $x⋅y=1$ in the multiplicative group $\pmod{65537}$ (with 65536 mapped to the 16-bit value `0x0000`), and you make absolutely no step towards computing that $y$ when $x$ is 53120 or hexadecimal `CF80`, your goal.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the multiplicative inverse of $a$ is defined to be that value $b$ for which $a \times b = 1$, where $\times$ is the multiplication operation in the field/ring/group in question.

Because we're talking about the group of multiplication modulo 65537, that means that the problem is, given $a$, find $b$ such that $ab \bmod 65537 = 1$.

Now, the % operator is C doesn't do it.  The classical way is to use the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm), where the two inputs to the algorithm is $a$ and $65537$; and have it find a solution to the equation $ax + 65537y = GCD(a, 65537) = 1$; the value $x$ is the multiplicative inverse you're looking for.

Of course, since there are only 65536 possible inverses, another possibility is simply have a table of the 65536 possible inverses, and just do a lookup.  In that case, you can use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to build the table.

Oh, and as a reminder; idea interprets the 0000 bit pattern as the value 65536 as far as multiplication is concerned (as the value 0 doesn't have an inverse).

Comment: I can't understand how can I get the value of "9194" in Extended Euclidean Algorithm...

Comment: @goldroger: if you run the EEA exactly as given on the wiki page, you come up with a value $x=-28269$.  If we take this value modulo 65537 (e.g. add 65537 to it), we find it is equivalent to 37268, which is exactly the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to exponentiate the value you want to invert by $65537-2$. You can do this quickly using the shortest addition chain for powering $65535$ modulo $65537$:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
a_0 &=& {\tt\text{0xcf80}} \\
a_1 &=& a_0 \cdot a_0 \\
a_2 &=& a_1 \cdot a_0 \\
a_3 &=& a_2 \cdot a_2 \\
a_4 &=& a_3 \cdot a_3 \\
a_5 &=& a_4 \cdot a_2 \\
a_6 &=& a_5 \cdot a_5 \\
a_7 &=& a_6 \cdot a_6 \\
a_8 &=& a_7 \cdot a_7 \\
a_9 &=& a_8 \cdot a_8 \\
a_{10} &=& a_9 \cdot a_5 \\
a_{11} &=& a_{10} \cdot a_{10} \\
a_{12} &=& a_{11} \cdot a_{11} \\
a_{13} &=& a_{12} \cdot a_{12} \\
a_{14} &=& a_{13} \cdot a_{13} \\
a_{15} &=& a_{14} \cdot a_{14} \\
a_{16} &=& a_{15} \cdot a_{15} \\
a_{17} &=& a_{16} \cdot a_{16} \\
a_{18} &=& a_{17} \cdot a_{17} \\
a_{19} &=& a_{18} \cdot a_{10} \\
inv &=& {\tt\text{0x9194}} = a_{19}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Beware that depending on how you perform the modular multiplications in IDEA, you may be susceptible to some [timing attacks](https://www.schneier.com/paper-side-channel.html).

Comment: That solution uses that for $p$ prime and $x\not=0\bmod p$, we can compute $x^{-1}\bmod p$ as $x^{p-2}\bmod p$; and builds the 65535th power by a (non-obvious) [addition chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation). Of course, operator $⋅$ is multiplication $\pmod{65537}$ (with $65536$ mapped to the 16-bit value `0x0000`), as used elsewhere in IDEA. This is useful in the context of preparing a key for decryption in IDEA, for it gives the right result without any test, thus no timing dependency beyond that of $⋅$, which would leak information about the key.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to compute a multiplicative inverse to encrypt or decrypt, in IDEA.  All you need is the ability to multiply modulo $2^{16}+1$.  See [How can I implement the "Multiplication Modulo" and "Addition Modulo" operations in IDEA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5076/351)

Key generation involves computing a multiplicative inverse.  One way to compute the multiplicative inverse is using the extended Euclidean algorithm.  Another way is to raise to the power $2^{16}-1$.  Either way works.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a small ruby program which calculates the inverse with respect to the IDEA multiplication. The IDEA multiplication is defined on [0..65535] by identifying 0 with 65536 and multiplying mod 65537 (the 4-th Fermat prime). The IDEA-multiplication can be calculated with data-independent timing as you can see below in mult. The addition chain used by Samuel Neves for the exponentiation can be obtained by the factorization 65535 = 3*5*17*257 so that can write it in a double loop (in the outer loop "4.times do |i|" the variable i takes the values 0,1,2,3).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def mult(x, y)
  x, y = (x-1) & 0xffff, (y-1)& 0xffff
  z = (x+y+x*y) % 0x10001
  z = (z+1) & 0xffff
end

def inv(x)
  4.times do |i|
    y = mult(x, x)
    ((1<<i)-1).times do
      y = mult(y, y)
    end
    x = mult(x, y)
  end
  x
end

puts('0x%x' % inv(0xcf80))
```

The output of the program is

```
0x9194
```