# How do I generate decryption keys for the IDEA algorithm from the 128 bit key?

Tags: key-derivation, idea

I am trying to implement IDEA algorithm in C#, just to learn how it works. I have taken a 128 bit binary key and generated the 52 encryption keys using the following code:

```
static ushort[] getKeys(string binaryKey)
{
        ushort[] keys = new ushort[52];
        int index = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int bitPos = 0;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            if (index == 52)
                break;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            binaryKey = binaryKey.Substring(25) + binaryKey.Substring(0, 25);
        }
        return keys;
}
```

but now I cannot understand how to get those decryption keys. I couldn't find enough text on the matter too.

Comment: For folks who don't know C#, `ushort` is a 16 bit unsigned data type and the `string binaryKey` in my code is strictly 128 bits.

Comment: If I understand IDEA right, you need the same sub-keys for decryption as for encryption. For the $\odot$ operations, you then need to divide, not multiply (which means multiplying with the multiplicative inverse of your key).

Comment: Please note also that this is not a programming site, so it would be better if you express what your program does as a formula (or a series thereof) instead of a source code in any programming language.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: That doesn't seem to work, although I believe that the sub-keys generated by the above method are correct!
+I understand that this is not a programming Q&A but I thought they are closely related, to some extent. I'll be careful next time.

Comment: How are you using them for decryption? The decryption function is not simply the same as the encryption function with other keys, you have to invert the steps, too.

Comment: How would you invert the steps whose output was an XOR or two 16 bit values? You only have the resultant XORed value and you need the operands.

Comment: Sorry. Ignore what I said above. The cipher is specially made so that encryption is the same as decryption, with different keys derived from the encryption keys. I'll write up an answer from the description in [the IDEA paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.3451) later, if not someone else does earlier.

Comment: For computation of the modular inverse, [try this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6693/555). The rest is straightforward.

Comment: I did not had any problem with 'Modular Inverse'. I am stuck with the rest of the straightforward!

Comment: @Nikhil Girraj: see `invert_key` in that [reference code](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/gnupg.old/contrib/idea.c), which computes the decryption subkeys from the encryption subkeys.